# Clarification regarding storage account in web applications

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cloud-services

I have an on-premises mvc application with a database calls to one more server.

When I deploy this application to windows azure, I am curious to know what will be stored in the storage account for this cloud service?
Is it database records or something else?

Comment: As it stands now, the question is quite broad. I would suggest you reading up on Azure Storage first: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you mentioned creating a Cloud Service (so, I'm assuming Web Role for your MVC app): The deployment needs a storage account, at a minimum, for storing diagnostic log information, as well as your cloud service package and configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Storage account is mostly used for "Blob" storage. In Azure environment we should not prefer to store blob data( like image and doc/PDF ) in database.best practice to store blob storage link.

Azure Storage provides the flexibility to store and retrieve large amounts of unstructured data, such as documents and media files with **Azure Blobs**; structured nosql based data with **Azure Tables**; reliable messages with **Azure Queues** and use SMB based **Azure Files** for migrating on-premises applications to the cloud.

for Overview and reference : http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/services/storage/

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking what the Storage service offers. Rather, the OP was (I believe) asking what the Storage service is being used for, specifically for the MVC app deployment they just performed, and why they needed to specify a storage account in the first place.

Comment: thanks David for your consideration, that is why I am trying to brief about Azure Storage best practices in my first para

Comment: I understand. It's just that this really isn't the place to post about best practices (nor is it relevant to the question). And the decision to use a particular storage service is not necessarily a best practice, as there are many things to consider, including performance, limitations, etc. And your assertion that storage is mostly used for Blob Storage: That's a decent guess, but it's not really proven (nor relevant).